# wso2iot-3.0.0 device registration steps

Tags: wso2

pls help and suggest to register android (4.4.3) device in wso2iot-3.0.0

I have completed below steps if any correction/recommendation, then please suggest.

1. Installed CentOS 7 (server os) with 8GB RAM
2. JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to "/opt/jdk1.7.0_79"
3. CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to "~/wso/broker"
4. started server by running below commands
    $ ./wso/broker/bin/wso2server/sh
    $ ./wso/core/bin/wso2server/sh
    $ ./wso/analytics/bin/wso2server/sh
5. logged in as admin in browser with https://10.0.26.145:9443/devicemgt
6. Received invitation email with user id and password for newly created user
7. In agent I am entering 10.0.26.145:9763

now problem is when i enters this user id and password (received in email) in wso2 agent in mobile its not proceeding (rotating continuously). Some times its showing error that "Incorrect User Information"......

Pls help into this......

Comment: At least you got there... wso2iot seems to be the most (un)intuitive product of wso2 to start with :/  you should have a look what is REALLY happening on the mobile web view. I have bad feeling there are some wrong redirects, just I don't recall where to configure them..

Comment: then how to troubleshoot / rectify wrong redirection?

Comment: Can I know how did you end up having the agent port to 9443 ?, Was it mentioned anywhere in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Agent URL should be 10.0.26.145:8280, From IOTS - 3.0.0, the api calls goes through the synapse gateway.

Comment: Is it necessary to modify default  agent .apk?

Comment: Are you trying this with multitenancy capability?, Could it be possible provide the agent logs ?